# UWP - SoftwareBitmap para Stream

Tags: c#, conversão-de-tipo, uwp

Eai pessoal,

Estou utilizando `MediaFrameReader` para capturar os frames de uma câmera USB em uma aplicação UWP, o retorno do evento `FrameArrived` me retorna um objeto do tipo SoftwareBitmap, tendo esse frame eu verifico se existe rosto humano utilizando `FaceDetector`, ao detectar essas faces eu pretendo utilizar o SDK do **FaceId** para verificar se este rosto está cadastrado, entretanto o SDK exige que eu envie uma imagem em estado de Stream, como eu posso fazer essa conversão?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode optar por utilizar o **BitmapDecoder**, como no [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070622/photo-capture-stream-to-softwarebitmap):

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
ImageEncodingProperties properties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(properties, stream);
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
SoftwareBitmap sfbmp = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
```

Comment: The first code is not possible, because I could not use Image in UWP, but the second and third gave me the necessary light to execute the code, updated as an answer!

Thanks a lot, I lost 2 days looking for this!

Comment: @RePinheiro I just updated the answer, I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Conversão:

```
        SoftwareBitmap frameBitmap = frame.SoftwareBitmap;
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frameBitmap.PixelWidth, frameBitmap.PixelHeight);
        frameBitmap.CopyToBuffer(bitmap.PixelBuffer);
        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await bitmap.ToStream(stream, BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);
        var detect = await faceClient.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(stream.AsStream());
```